# Error "unsupported_grant_type" when using the Sage One API

Tags: php, api, sage-erp, sage-one

I'm using the Sage One API Php from Eddie Harrison (https://github.com/eddieharrison/sageone-api-php). I'm trying to do basic authentication with the API, however it returns the following error:

> string(35) "{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"} " int(0) Warning:
>   json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mojo.eu.com/nf2015.mojo.eu.com/app/sageone/SageOne.php
>   on line 59

According to the Sage One API Documentation, the error "unsupported_grant_type" occurs when the wrong grant type is given. It should either be `authorization_code` or `refresh_token`. However, in the code it's clearly using `authorization_code`.

I have noticed that the URL's that the Sage One API library I am using are different to the ones in the documentation, but even changing these to the ones in the documentation doesn't solve the issue.

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data for the token request is serialized into JSON. According to the OAuth 2.0 specification the format of the entity-body is expected to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3